# HTML Agility Pack fails to find the node using XPath

Tags: .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to find a node of the page number 200 in the web page https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/page/2/. The XPath I got from chrome is `//*[@id="site-main"]/nav/div/a[4]`. But HTML Agility Pack is returning null when I try to fetch the node. Below is the sample code.

```
string url = "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/page/2/";
var doc = web.Load(url);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"site - main\"]/nav/div/a[4]");
```

How can I get the node and how should I troubleshoot these kind of issues with XPath?

Comment: There are spaces before and after the hyphen on the id in your code (`site - main`) and not on the original path.

Comment: Thanks @Anderson Pimentel. This seems to be a problem with visual studio editor. If that is copy pasted directly within the double quotes, visual studio editor is reformatting. Had to add double quotes after pasting or fix it manually. Hope there is an option to control that reformatting.

Comment: I thought there was a problem posting in SO. Glad this was the solution! I'm posting as an answer, so you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are spaces before and after the hyphen on the id in your code (`site - main`) and not on the original path.

Comment: Accepted Anderson's answer. Refer to my answer for the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a space before and after hyphen in `site-main`. These spaces were added by visual studio automatically when that string was copy pasted between the already existing double quotes. Solution is to add quotes after pasting or fixing it manually.

Added Anderson Pimental's comment as answer and thankful for that.  Thought of deleting this question but retaining this as others could also face this issue with Visual Studio.